# sql - Select from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have a table `users` and table `questions`. I want to select 5 random users from `users` table who has at least 20 queries (db.questions to_user = db.users id) in `questions` table. All I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users s 
WHERE exists (SELECT 20 
              FROM questions m 
              WHERE m.to_user = s.id) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more what you want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions q WHERE q.to_user = u.id) >= 20
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very very very much, Gordon! It works!

Comment: Nice, but if you will have lot of users and/or questions in your tables, you may want to use sharding.